# Backbone.js won't parse modified JSON

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, collections, model

This is really getting on my nerves and I don't understand what's causing it. I'm creating a prototype backbone.js app using a collection that is fetched from a static JSON file that is mocking a database response.

I have my view rendering with the collection data fine, but if I change a single letter in my JSON file the fetch method errors!?

By errors I mean the fetch method error callback is fired rather than the success callback.

The JSON is valid, for example I'll change:

```
{
   "hey": "hi"
}
```

to

```
{
   "hey": "ho"
}
```

and the view no longer renders unless I save the updated JSON with a new filename and update my collection URL to match the new filename.

I can't understand why it's doing this? I haven't posted any Javascript code because the code is fine.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Parse function:

```
this.collection.fetch({
        success: function(collection, response, options) {
          view.render();
        }
        , error: function(collection, response, options) {
          console.log("error");
        }
      })
```

I don't know how to find the actual error in those objects, the response.responseText is my JSON by the way.

Comment: Character encoding or something? It could be useful if you post what error your script throws, and also probably which part of the code throws this error?

Comment: Unless SublimeText2 is changing the character encoding randomly on save I don't think it's that. Parse code posted.

Comment: And what would a 'console.log("error:", response)' post? And also, can you check network tab in the browser console - do you get an error 4xx/5xx or is it pure Javascript error?